Thymeleaf th:each - How to disable generating the div tags
                <div class="question" th:each="question : ${questions}">
                    <h2 id="question" class="description" th:text="${question.description}">Question goes here</h2>
                    <div id="answer-buttons">
                        <button class="btn"><div class="answer" th:text="${question.possibleAnswers.get(0).content}" th:classappend="${question.correctAnswer == 1 ? 'correct-answer' : ''}">Answer 1</div></button>
                        <button class="btn"><div class="answer" th:text="${question.possibleAnswers.get(1).content}" th:classappend="${question.correctAnswer == 2 ? 'correct-answer' : ''}">Answer 2</div></button>
                        <button class="btn"><div class="answer" th:text="${question.possibleAnswers.get(2).content}" th:classappend="${question.correctAnswer == 3 ? 'correct-answer' : ''}">Answer 3</div></button>
                        <button class="btn"><div class="answer" th:text="${question.possibleAnswers.get(3).content}" th:classappend="${question.correctAnswer == 4 ? 'correct-answer' : ''}">Answer 4</div></button>
                    </div>
                    <button id="next-btn">Next</button>
                </div>

If I figured correctly, th:each from the above code makes a new division for every question in questions, similar to this:
            <div class="quiz">
                <div class="question">
                    <h2 id="question" class="description">Question</h2>
                    <div id="answer-buttons">
                        <button class="btn"><div class="answer">Answer 1</div></button>
                        <button class="btn"><div class="answer correct-answer">Answer 2</div></button>
                        <button class="btn"><div class="answer">Answer 3</div></button>
                        <button class="btn"><div class="answer">Answer 4</div></button>
                    </div>
                    <button id="next-btn">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>

Questions come from database and I have js file to handle them but in order to do so I don't want extra html bodies to be created.
So my question is, does Thymeleaf have some disabler mechanism for above mentioned problem or do I need to change the structure of my code?
For any use, here is how my script handles the data:
const questionsFromDb = document.querySelectorAll('.question');

// Template
const questions = [
    {
        question: "Which is the largest animal on the planet?",
        answers: [
            {text: "Shark", correct: false},
            {text: "Blue whale", correct: true},
            {text: "Elephant", correct: false},
            {text: "Giraffe", correct: false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "Which is the smallest country on the planet?",
        answers: [
            {text: "Vatican City", correct: true},
            {text: "Bhutan", correct: false},
            {text: "Nepal", correct: false},
            {text: "Shri Lanka", correct: false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "Which is the largest desert on the planet?",
        answers: [
            {text: "Kalahari", correct: false},
            {text: "Gobi", correct: false},
            {text: "Sahara", correct: false},
            {text: "Antarctica", correct: true}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "Which is the smallest continent on the planet?",
        answers: [
            {text: "Asia", correct: false},
            {text: "Australia", correct: true},
            {text: "Arctic", correct: false},
            {text: "Africa", correct: false}
        ]
    }
];

// Parsing Data
questionsFromDb.forEach(questionFromDb => {
    const questionDescription = questionFromDb.querySelector('.description').innerText;
    const answerElements = questionFromDb.querySelectorAll('.answer');

    const answers = [];

    answerElements.forEach((answerElement, index) => {
        const answerText = answerElement.innerText;
        const isCorrect = answerElement.classList.contains('correct-answer');

        answers.push({ text: answerText, correct: isCorrect });
    });

    questions.push({
        question: questionDescription,
        answers: answers
    });
});

// ... Non-relative code below


Adding new div is a valid approach and u can have additional div without style, however if u want to remove tag you can use  th:remove="tag" or th:inline mechanism however it is not good approach to style test ,respect to  expression lang methodology, also adding html id is not correct way and you may add additional data to id such : th:id="${'question_'+ status.id}"
.
Also your template seems to be json!
if u ask me , I think the best approach is not use thymleaf in such list ui , u can use js data tables such tabulator with rest and play with js instead
